# Slack API using websocket not getting events after successful connection

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, slack-api

Using PHP/Laravel and WebSocketClient and Guzzle.

I am able to auth through Guzzle to get WSS URL and further able to connect using the provided WSS URL.  I can dump the hello message:

```
{#713
  +"type": "hello"
  +"num_connections": 1
  +"debug_info": {#716
    +"host": "applink-12"
    +"build_number": 42
    +"approximate_connection_time": 18060
  }
  +"connection_info": {#721
    +"app_id": "XXXXXXX"
  }
}
```

The app_id matches what I am expecting.

However this seems to be the only message I receive. If I type in an IM message (in the Slack interface) to the bot I get nothing. If I use a slash command (in Slack) I immediately get:

```
/options failed with the error "dispatch_failed"
```

Here is a my handler loop for incoming messages - I run this from a console command:

```
$this->info("Listening to Slack Events");
$webClient = new WebSocketClient($this->wss."&debug_reconnects=true", ['persistent' => true, 'timeout' => 1800]);
// Listen to incoming slack messages
while (true) {
  try {
    $message = json_decode($webClient->receive());
    if ($message) {
         $messageType = $message->type;
         dump($message);  //Any event message from Slack should be dumped to the console
         dump($messageType);  

         switch($messageType){
           case 'hello':
               $webClient->setTimeout($message->debug_info->approximate_connection_time);
               $this->info("Approximate Timeout = ".$message->debug_info->approximate_connection_time /60 . " minutes");
           break;
           case 'disconnect':
                $this->info("Closing Connection");
                $webClient->close();
                $this->info("Closed Connection");
                exit();
           break;
           default:
                $this->error($messageType . " wasn't handled");
                $webClient->send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
      }
 }
} catch (\WebSocket\ConnectionException $e) {
 if ($e->getMessage() == 'Empty read; connection dead?')
 {
      $this->error("Timeout.. continuing");
 }
 else
 {
      $this->error("Failed:".$e->getMessage());
      return ['error' => $e->getMessage()];
 }
```

}

What am I doing wrong and how can I debug this further?

Other notes:

- socket mode is enabled via the slack api UI
- From what I can tell all APP level and Bot level scopes are correct

Comment: would you mind sharing the slash command endpoint in your Laravel App?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response: It's just a websocket and dumping what ever messages comes across. Per documentation when using websockets the endpoints aren't looked at or used

Comment: @SalmanMalik I added my hander to the question - hopefully that brings clarity

Comment: *"If I type in an IM message to the bot"* How do you do that? How is that related to the posted code? It's really hard to understand what you are doing or trying to do.

Comment: @Olivier in slack - If I message the bot (@MyBot) it should be generating a message event.  If I'm connected to Slack via websockets, my app should recieve that message event.  The code I show is just an event handler that dumps all messages from slack.  There's no logic there... I should just see the message get dumped out

Comment: Split the json_decode into two: `$incoming = $webClient->receive(); var_dump($incoming);` and check that the $incoming is not "null" or an object type. because if it is, your handler will bomb out. To address, only process if you have a string, and wrap the json_decode() in try/catch with THROW_EXCEPTIONS.

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation?

Comment: @Olivier - Yes - and it's quite good.  I can pull messages and create webhooks... I just can't get the websocket to work (beyond the initial "hello" that tells us we've established a connection) - https://api.slack.com/apis/connections/socket